# Prove using the formal definition of limit that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\cos x)$ does not exist.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

My attempt: Let $\epsilon=1$ then the inequality $|\cos x-L|<1$ should hold for $x>M$,where $M>0$. Suppose that $\exists$ an $M>0$ such that the inequality holds. Then $$|\cos x-L|\leq|\cos x|+|L|\leq 1+|L|<1$$ However this implies that $|L|<0$ which is contradiction. Hence the limit does not exist.

I would like to know whether this approach is correct or not. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is wrong: you cannot deduce $|\cos x|+|L|\leq 1$  starting from $ |\cos x-L|<1$ and from $|\cos x-L|\leq|\cos x|+|L|$! The proof goes in a different way: the point is that the function $f(x)$ assumes values -1 and +1 for $x$ bigger than an arbitrary large number $M$ and whatever is $L$, $L$ has distance greater than 1 from $+1$ or from $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake because you might have $1\le |\cos x|+|L|$. Pick $a,b\in \Bbb R$ such that $|\cos a-\cos b|:=c\ne0$. Let $\epsilon =\frac c2$. Notice that we can find $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $a+2n\pi, b+2n\pi\ge M$ so we get

$$|\cos a-L|< \epsilon$$
and $$|\cos b-L|<\epsilon$$
hence using triangular inequality
$$c=|\cos a-\cos b|\le |\cos a-L|+|\cos b-L|<c$$
which is a contradiction.